# Difference Between Kentico hierarchical Viewer and Universal Viewer

Tags: kentico

I know Hierarchical Viewer inherits from Universal Viewer but when to use hierarchical and Universal Viewer in Kentico and what's the main difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hierarchical viewer should be used when you want to display some kid of hierarchy, typically it is like displaying the tree structure of the content tree. While the universal viewer displays more flat structure.